# I want to print the 3rd highest value along with the 'Id' as the pic

Tags: python, pandas

> From here I want to print the 3rd highest value along with the 'Id'. A help would be appreciated

`Most_Calori_Burner.nlargest(3)`

[image: series]

Comment: could you paste your input as editable text instead of img?

Comment: you mean the code? I am giving pic because my df is big. I have been asked to the the find out who burn max calories then find out third most person to burn max calories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRy this,

```
df.groupby('Id')['Calories'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index().iloc[2]
```

- Sort your dataframe in descending order
- Reset index and take 3rd value.

Comment: yes this is good only one thing, we have say .sort_values(ascending=False) because the series was coming in ascending direction. Thank you so much sir!

Comment: sure, Please give me a up vote to gain reputation score. I am very new here